# how to return string n times from a python function, such that it is printed n times with space in between

Tags: python, string

I am supposed to Write a function called `"show_excitement"` where the string
`"I am super excited for this course!"` is returned exactly
5 times, where each sentence is separated by a single space.
I  can only have the string once in my code.

I have tried following code, but I think it is wrong somewhere. Please  give an improved or alternate solution.

```
def show_excitement(str,n):
    if(n==0):
        return str
    else:
        show_excitement(str,n-1)

str="I am super excited for this course!"
print show_excitement(str,5)
```

Comment: The problem with your code is 1. the `else` does not return anything, `show_excitement(str,n-1)` may run but you are doing nothing with it, like returning via `return show_excitement(str,n-1)` 2. you are likely confusing return of a function and printing - you either want to print str each time the function runs (function returns nothing) or create an empty string and append `'\n'+str` 5 times and return this (function returns string to print). A function that returns `" ".join([str] * n)` seems most pythonic.

Comment: No, just giving example of *doing something with it*. I'll add code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def show_excitement(str,n):
    print str*n

str=" I am super excited for this course!"

show_excitement(str,5)
```

Comment: Invalid for python3, use () when printing values.

Comment: the answer was for python2 as OP used print instead of print()

Answer (score 1):

What about something like:

```
" ".join(["hello"] * 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
def show_excitement(str,n):
    if(n==0):
        return str
    else:
        #return the str N times
        return str*n


str="I am super excited for this course!"

print show_excitement(str,5)
```

Comment: I guess he is trying to use recursion

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to print it using recursion. Try below using recursion.

```
def show_excitement(str,n):
    global result
    if(n==0):
        return result.strip()
    else:
        result=result+" "+str
        return show_excitement(str,n-1)


result = ""
str="I am super excited for this course!"
print show_excitement(str,5)
```

Output:

`I am super excited for this course! I am super excited for this course! I am super excited for this course! I am super excited for this course! I am super excited for this course!`

Answer (score 1):

```
def show_excitement():
    str = "I am super excited for this course!"
    return  (str + " ")* 5

print show_excitement()
```

Answer (score 0):

Return **does not** print strings!

```
def show_excitement(str,n):
        print(str)
        if(n!=1):
            show_excitement(str,n-1)

str="I am super excited for this course!"
show_excitement(str,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use recursion:

```
def show_excitement(str, n):
    global return_str
    return_str += str
    if n == 0:
        return return_str
    else:
        show_excitement(str, n - 1)


return_str = ""
str = "I am super excited for this course!"
show_excitement(str, 5)
print(return_str)
```

NOTE: The str variable name is not the perfect one. In my opinion you should avoid the recursion if it is possible. This is a simple task and you can solve it many different way without recursion.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comments (using python 3):

Version with no return:

```
def show_excitement(str,n):
    if(n==0):
        print('\n') # last bit of code that runs in the function, no return
    else:
        print(str, end=' ')
        return show_excitement(str, n-1)

str="I am super excited for this course!"
show_excitement(str, 5) # returns None but prints to console

# result - note there will be space on end printed that you can't see
# I am super excited for this course! I am super excited for this course! I am super excited for this course! I am super excited for this course! I am super excited for this course!
```

Version building string and returning a string object:

```
def show_excitement(str, n, str_built=''):
    if(n==0):
        return str_built.strip() # clear last ' '
    else:
        str_built += str + ' ' # can be changed to '\n' if needed on new line
        return show_excitement(str, n-1, str_built)


str="I am super excited for this course!"
show_excitement(str, 5) # string object
# 'I am super excited for this course! I am super excited for this course! I am super excited for this course! I am super excited for this course! I am super excited for this course!'
print(show_excitement(str, 5))
# I am super excited for this course! I am super excited for this course! I am super excited for this course! I am super excited for this course! I am super excited for this course!
```

I recommend the following version unless you have to use recursion in which case I would use the string builder version.

```
def show_excitement(str, n, sep=" "):
    return sep.join([str] * n)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def show_excitement():

    return ("I am super excited for this course!" + " ")*5

print(show_excitement())
```

---

Output:

> I am super excited for this course! I am super excited for this course! I am super excited for this course! I am super excited for this course! I am super excited for this course!

Answer (score 0):

```
def show_excitement(stri,n): 
    if(n==1):
        return stri
    else:
        return show_excitement(stri,n-1)+" "+stri
print(show_excitement("I am super excited for this course!",5))
```

Comment: Maybe you can add some explanation to the code? Examples would be, where the attempt of the person asking failed or, what this code does. The person asking is starting to learn the language, so would clearly benefit from that. on the other hand, there are already answers and an accepted one to this solved question. What is special about your answer? You should indicate that, I think.